# What does touch * do?

Tags: shell, unix, glob

I was asked a question in an interview recently - How you will delete a file named '*'?
So I tried creating a file as - touch *. When I list, I don't see this file. When I edit (vi *). I opens up a file with random text.
So what is touch *?

Answer (score 1):

Shells expand `*`. `touch *` is `touch every nonhidden file in the current directory`. If you want to create a file literally named `*`, you need to quote it: `touch \*` (or `touch '*'` or `touch "*"` and the equivalent for other commands such as `rm`).

Comment: Or `touch '*'` or `touch "*"` as globs are not expanded inside quotes.  To remove the file named `*`, use `rm '*'` or `rm \*` or `rm "*"`.

Comment: @codeforester Thanks for the info I probably should have included. I have now.

Answer (score 1):

You should look up unix "globbing".

The shell will look at the command and replace * with every file (not starting with '.' or hidden) unless you escape this special character * just or put it in single quotes '*'

You can use this to apply a command to many files without actually listing them manually.

If you want to see what * expands and how you can escape it to you can run the following commands:

```
  echo *
  echo '*'
  echo \*
```

You can also use this with more specific pattern like

```
  <command> a* # run the command on the list of file starting with a
```

If you want to see what the terminal actually executed when you ran touch * run:

```
 echo touch *
```

The touch command as others have explained before will either create a empty file if the filename does not exist, or update the last modified timestamp on existing files. So you just updated the last modified timestamps of every non hidden file in the directory you executed the command in.

Note that this happens before your command is ever called. And if the list of file is VERY large (millions) you will get an error as the list of files will be too large to fit into the command buffer (aka the string of your expanded command will be too large)

Further reading : https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`man touch`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/touch.1.html), `touch` changes a timestamp of a file. If the file doesn't exist, it creates it empty, unless `-c` or `-h` parameters are given.

In Bash, `*` is a globbing character which expands to every non-hidden file and directory in the current directory. That means `touch *` will change the timestamp of every file and directory in the current directory, if there is any, to the current date and time.